# Is it possible to put if statement with AND comparison into statement or for loop

Tags: arduino

I am writing a piece of code in the Arduino IDE. I have an IF statement which has a long comparison of arrays to see if they are all equal to 0. If they are then carry out the code within the statement.

I'm not sure if this is possible but thought I would ask if the code can be simplified. For all the other code I have been able to use for loops, but I cannot see this working with this statement.

The statement will have about 20 arrays to compare in the end.

```
if (Tbit[0] == 0 && Tbit[1] == 0 && Tbit[2] == 0 && Tbit[3] == 0){
  digitalWrite(Tout[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Tout[1], HIGH);
}
```

**EDIT UPDATE**

I have tried PiNaKa30 suggestion below which I thought would work but still the outputs for the HIGH statement are not being carried out. Below is the full void loop code with my code above commented out and PiNaKa30 codes added.

The bit being read at the beginning only goes HIGH '1' for 1 second when a command input to the arduino is received. Normal state is 0

```
    void loop() {
    cmri.process();
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
       Tbit[i] = (cmri.get_bit(i));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
      if (Tbit[i] == 1){
         digitalWrite(Tout[i], !Tbit[i]);
      }
    }

  //  if (Tbit[0] == 0 && Tbit[1] == 0){
   //   digitalWrite(Tout[0], HIGH);
  //    digitalWrite(Tout[1], HIGH);
  //  }


    for(int i=0; i < 2; i++){
      val = val || Tbit[i];    // Even a single 1 in Tbit will make val=1
    }

    if(val == 0){
      digitalWrite(Tout[0], HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Tout[1], HIGH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain a variable which will be the **OR** of all values of the array. This variable must be updated as soon as any value changes in the array, and be used in your if statement.

```
int val = 0; // initialize

updateVal(){
  for(int i=0;i<Tbit.length;i++)
    val = val || Tbit[i];    // Even a single 1 in Tbit will make val=1
}

if(val == 0){
  digitalWrite(Tout[0], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(Tout[1], HIGH);
}
```

I am assuming here that Tbit can only have values 0 and 1. Otherwise change the function slightly to suit your needs.

Comment: I thought this would work but I cannot get it to run the if statement when the input bits are equal to 0. I've edited the question with the full void loop. Yes the bits are only 1 or 0

Comment: Weird! Are the values you are getting of type int? Otherwise you can even try with bool types

Comment: yes they are 0 or 1 bit. I thing it was where I was initializing val at the start of the program. By putting it in the void loop at the start it ensured val was always equal to zero at start of the loop. I agree looking at what you have written I thought it would work. Nice job anyway still got what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with the help of PiNaKa30 suggestion and a little tweeting.

```
void loop() {
    val = 0;
    cmri.process();
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
       Tbit[i] = (cmri.get_bit(i));
    }

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
      if (Tbit[i] == 1){
         digitalWrite(Tout[i], !Tbit[i]);
      }
    }

    for(int i=0; i < 2; i++){
      val = Tbit[i];    // Even a single 1 in Tbit will make val=1
    }

    if(val == 0){
      digitalWrite(Tout[0], HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Tout[1], HIGH);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you looking for an exception its easier to start from the other side:

I would have divided it into two parts
first create a variable to tell us result of a check

```
bool correct=1;
```

next check each if it contains any other then correct value

```
for(uint8_t i=0; i<**Number of array members**;i++) {
```

Now check if any of them are wrong, and if yes assume incorrect

```
if(Tbit[i]!=0) correct=0;
```

and now only process your code if none was incorrect

```
if(correct) ...
```

Which would at the end look like:

```
void loop() { // or any while statement you would have it in
   cmri.process();
   for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
       Tbit[i] = (cmri.get_bit(i));
   }

   bool correct=1;
   for(uint8_t i=0; i<**Number of array members**;i++) {
      if(Tbit[i]!=0) correct=0;
   }
   if(correct) {
      digitalWrite(Tout[0], HIGH);
      digitalWrite(Tout[1], HIGH);
   }
}
```

Comment: if you want to save a 1 byte of RAM, you can put it inside brackets as variable **correct** stays defined during the loop